# save and load attribute to xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

Here is my code:

settings.xaml

```
        <TextBox x:Name="txtNumber" PreviewMouseDown="myKeyPad_PreviewMouseDown" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-253,-123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here too...." />
        <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="myKeyPad_PreviewMouseDown" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-114,-123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here too...."/>

        <TextBox x:Name="rtb1" PreviewMouseDown="myKeyPad_PreviewMouseDown" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-253,-84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here too...."  />
        <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="myKeyBoard_PreviewMouseDown" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-114,-83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here too...."/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0.4,0.2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="ID:" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Margin="5" Width="200"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Name:" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Margin="5" Width="200"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Age:" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAge" Margin="5" Width="200" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter text here too...."/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Wolle:" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtWolle" Margin="5" Width="200" Custom:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter Wolle here too...."/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Save" x:Name="Save" Click="Save_Click" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="97,5,97.4,5"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

the Setting.xaml.cs show so:

```
 private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = this.txtId.Text;
        string name = this.txtName.Text;
        string age = this.txtAge.Text;
        string Wolle = this.txtWolle.Text;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");

        //Create a root element
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");
        //Create a sub element
        XmlNode subNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");
        //Create subNode's attribute
        XmlAttribute idAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Id");
        idAttribute.Value = id;

        XmlAttribute nameAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
        nameAttribute.Value = name;

        XmlAttribute ageAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Age");
        ageAttribute.Value = age;

        XmlAttribute WolleAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Wolle");
        WolleAttribute.Value = Wolle;

        subNode.Attributes.Append(idAttribute);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(nameAttribute);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(ageAttribute);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(WolleAttribute);

        rootNode.AppendChild(subNode);
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        xmlDoc.Save("User.xml");

        MessageBox.Show("Created Successful");
    }
```

how i can read the Attributes back in my TextBox on Application Start?

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend using LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument. It will make your life *much* simpler.

Comment: i am a beginner and search the web for a good easy tutorial ... but all examples to hard for me.

Comment: Well I would start off by trying to build a *console* app that does what you want to, following a LINQ to XML tutorial. That way you won't have all the complexity of WPF at the same time.

Comment: hmm: a console app is not what i want. I can write XML and now i want read the Attributes back in the field .. also checkboxes. i find a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwAamiBq3uA but i have a error in my App when i am click the saving button.

Comment: You need to separate out your tasks: parsing XML in a console app is exactly the same as parsing XML in a WPF app, but it's a lot easier to focus on just the XML part when you don't have a GUI to worry about. Get that working, then transfer that knowledge to your WPF app. Learn one thing at a time.

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit better? You just dump some code and it is not really clear to me what you want, what you tried, and how it fails.

Comment: it is very easy ... i want save Setting Parameters from a Field or Checkboxes in a XML or txt file. When i am open my Application i want that the Setting Parameters are show  in the Field.